# Unity PostLateUpdate.FinishFrameRendering using 60-70% CPU on Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, profiling

So I am trying to develop a game for Android and I stared profiling it. One thing I noticed is that the PostLateUpdae.FinishFrameRendering is using about 60% of my phone's CPU all the time. I've searched the internet for a fix but couldn't really find any good ones. What I want to achieve is reduce the usage of this particular process since it's the only one left for me to fix. The game looks like this, and it's mostly UI, no physics, all that could use much cpu is the cubes that move on the x axis at all time.[image: Profiler][image: GameLook]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's Main render function for URP.
You need to optimize your rendering.
Try to turn off some things, and see how it affects framerate

- Postprocess
- ligts
- different parts of scene
- quality settings

Minimize drawcalls
Split canvaces
Minimize overdraw
Dont use postprocess

Comment: Thanks for answering, turning off posproceessing actually improved it a lot. I also lowered some things in quality settings before. I only have one question left: if i split the canvases and make one that's only for dynamic objects how much will it improve my frame? Turning off postprocessing got me from 25 fps to 38 fps in the most loaded scenes. I just want to know if it's worth the time to it.

Comment: It depends on complexity of your scene. Try to find something like "canvas layout" in profiler to see how much time it takes. Dont remember exact function name

Comment: I tried finding canvas-related processes but couldn't find any that would use a lot of cpu. So that's a good thing, anyway, thanks for everything.